# reason for finding a spanning tree

Tags: graph-theory

Given a graph G, if the graph is interconnected, possibly containing a cycle, who do we find a minimum spanning tree at all? Most texts I've seen don't seem to explain the reason at all. Why don't we find a subgraph in the graph possibly containing a cycle whose weight is minimized, possibly by removal of some edges?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want a *connected* spanning subgraph whose total edge weight is minimized, it will necessarily be a tree. Trees are precisely the minimally connected graphs: graphs that don't contain any edge you can remove and still have a connected graph.

If you don't need the subgraph to be connected, then the total edge weight is minimized by not taking any edges at all...

Comment: say for a 4 vertex graph, if I traverse in this ABCD graph, from A to D the cost is 10 and if from AtoBtoCtoD the cost is 20, so...... come to think of it you're right,it would be a tree, is there a mathematical proof for  this?(just leaving my knowledge barier undeleted for those who could fall in the same pit)

Comment: Usually, a tree is defined as a connected graph with no cycles. As a result, if a connected spanning subgraph is not a tree, then it contains a cycle, and you can delete any edge of the cycle to reduce the weight.